# Can't create a JMS stream in Oracle Stream Analytics

Tags: jms, oracle-streams

I'm trying out Oracle Stream Analytics 12.2.1 and want to create a stream to receive JMS messages from my ActiveMQ broker in the standalone server domain that I set up.  I have a minimal setup with Java 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (only installed the fmw_12.2.1.1.0_osa.jar file and ran the Configuration Wizard to get things going).

I am able to start the standalone domain and log in to it.  From the Catalog screen I clicked the "Create New Item" menu button and selected to create a new Stream.  The the Create Stream wizard I set a name and set the stream type to JMS.

The second screen of the Create Stream wizard is where I get stuck.  The Oracle documentation on JMS is spotty at best, but I have found a couple places that imply that I should be able to type the URL to connect to my JMS broker on this screen, but instead, the "Connection" option is an empty dropdown that says "No matches found" when I click it.

[image]

I've tried creating a new Connection from the "Create New Item" menu button, but JMS is not an option for a type of connection to create so I'm stuck there too.

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

What is supported is working with JMS on a Weblogic server, so you first need to create a connection to a Weblogic server, then it will appear in the connection dropdown in your JMS stream wizard.

Comment: I didn't see a way to create a connection to a Weblogic server either.  In any case the documentation seems to imply that any JMS provider would work.  Would be a bummer if JMS really just means WebLogic JMS.